# Angular/Typescript, this.$resource is not a function

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ngresource

I'm getting a TypeError: this.$resource is not a function. This is my code

```
export class DataAccessService
    implements IDataAccessService {

    static $inject = ["$resource"];
    constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
    }

    getTravelExpenseType(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<T> {
        return this.$resource('URL:id', {}, {});
    }
}

common.service("dataAccessService",
    [DataAccessService]);
```

Comment: are you loading your dependency angular-resource.js ?
<script src="path/to/angular-resource.js"></script>

Comment: How do you use `getTravelExpenseType` method?

Comment: @Arno_Geismar Yes, I'm loading the angular-resource.js in index.html

Comment: @dsfq             `var traveExpenseTypeResource = dataAccessService.getTravelExpenseType();

            traveExpenseTypeResource.query((data) => {
                this.travelExpenseTypes = data;
            });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> common.service("dataAccessService",
>     [DataAccessService]);
> ```

The problem is that you're passing an array as your service definition. When you do that, you're supposed to list the dependencies to inject in the array first, and your constructor as the last element. Since you're not listing any dependencies to inject, nothing gets injected.

Just get rid of the array:

```
common.service("dataAccessService", DataAccessService);
```